# Replace word in list with another

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a program that is taking a sentence and splitting up each word into a list called 'words'. What this would look like is I input a sentence like "I love cows" and the program will split it into the list 'words'. The list will look like `words = ['i','hate','cows']`. I have that part down, but I want to be able to replace words like 'i' with other words like 'you'. This is a chunk of code I'm trying to get to work:

```
def word_identify(words):
parts_of_speech = []
for word in words:
    if word == 'help':
        help_info(help)
    if word == '?':            
        print "This is a question."
        return 12
    elif word == 'why':
        print "This is a question!"
        return 12
    elif word  == 'am':
        word = 'are'
        return 10
    elif word == 'i':
        word = ' you'
        return 10
    else:
        #new_words.append(word)
        return 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. The returns need to just me ignored, they trigger another portion of the program. I want the list 'words' to be updated with the new words.

Many thanks!!!

**Edit**
Thank you guys for the response!@Nammi you are very helpful, but if you tell me how to fix the problem with it only replace one of the two if they both appear in the list that would be great! Thanks so much guys!

The problem that still exists:

```
How are you? I am sad
Why are you am sad?
None
Am I sad
Why are are i sad? 
None
```

Do not take notice of the double 'are' I have handled that.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 3):

### You can use list comprehension, as follows:

```
new = ['you' if word == 'i' else word for word in words]
```

This runs as:

```
>>> words = ['i','hate','cows']
>>> new = ['you' if word == 'i' else word for word in words]
>>> new
['you', 'hate', 'cows']
>>>
```

### Or, for a more *verbose* solution,

Just use a basic `for` loop:

```
words = ['i','hate','cows']
new = []
for i in words:
    if i == 'i':
        new.append('you')
    elif i == 'am':
        new.append('are')
    elif i == 'why' or i == '?':
        print "This is a question!"
    else:
        new.append(i)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> words = ['i','hate','cows']
>>> new = []
>>> for i in words:
...     if i == 'i':
...         new.append('you')
...     elif i == 'am':
...         new.append('are')
...     elif i == 'why' or i == '?':
...         print "This is a question!"
...     else:
...         new.append(i)
... 
>>> new
['you', 'hate', 'cows']
>>>
```

Comment: Bud does this maintain the order or add to the end?

Comment: This would maintain order since the `for` loop starts at the top.

Comment: Your answer did pretty much encapsulate mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with use of the `map` function

```
words = ['i','hate','cows']
new_words = map(lambda x: 'you' if x == 'i' else x, words)
print new_words  #prints ['you', 'hate', 'cows']
```

This function takes an input list of size N and outputs a list with the exact same length. The lambda function applies a transformation to each element of the output array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a **for-in** loop, you could loop through by index.
Assigning a list element using its index overwrites whatever value is in the list with the new value. So you do not need to return the list after making your changes.

```
for i in range(0, len(words)):
    if (words[i] == "i"):
        words[i] = "you"
    elif (words[i] == "am"):
        words[i] = "are"
....
```

Comment: WOuld this replace one of the functions or the whole chunk of code?

Comment: The whole chunk. It would be helpful to have it in a function with 'words' as a parameter, but not necessary.

Comment: It only replaces one out of the two, not both. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems  like its only running once through, shouldn't it run mutiple times

Comment: It is accessing every element once, isn't that what you want? You would need to add each case in the loop, otherwise it would only check for "i" and "are"